# It is possible/safe to remove default folders in Artifactory?

Tags: artifactory

I have installed last version of Artifactory (4.15.0) and it comes with several default folders.

[image]

My questions are:

- What are those folders for?
- Is it possible/safe remove them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Artifactory comes pre-configured with a set of [repositories](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Repositories) of 3 types: [local](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Repositories#ConfiguringRepositories-LocalRepositories), [remote](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Repositories#ConfiguringRepositories-RemoteRepositories) and [virtual](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Repositories#ConfiguringRepositories-VirtualRepositories).
This set of repositories allows easy onboarding to Artifactory (assuming you are using Maven/Gradle) and reflects some best practices such as using virtual repositories.
If no one is using them right now, you can safely remove them with no harm done. You will need, however to create your own set of repositories.
The only repository you should not remove is the ["Trash Can"](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Browsing+Artifactory#BrowsingArtifactory-TrashCan) repository which is used for storing deleted artifacts for recovery purposes (you can disable it if you like to).

You can delete repositories by going to Admin > Repositories > Local (or Remote, Virutal), selecting the repository from the grid and clicking the "Delete" button.

[image]

Comment: You can delete them from the admin section. Go to Admin > Repositories > Local (or remote/virtual), select a repository from the grid and use the delete button that appears on the right side of the row